# Revision history suggests that I edited the post body, whereas I didn't

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, tags, revisions-list

I was doing some re-tagging and I noticed that the automatically generated revision comment says that I edited the post body where I only edited the tags.

- [Revision list](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/2230507/revisions)
- [Source before the edit](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/c59adca0-e591-45b3-b3b2-b77054425649/view-source)
- [Source after the edit](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/30cf2dfd-f193-476e-bc08-e94b424a54a3/view-source)

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, a retag is considered an edit which will spin off a new revision if it is done after the 5min grace of the previous edit/add.

Comment: @o.k.w, That's true. But normally, when just the tags are edited, automatically generated revision comment don't say "edited body", also the revision list doesn't show the post body for that revision. Example : http://stackoverflow.com/posts/2218838/revisions

Comment: you've got a point. I just added a tag on your post and it shows up as just edited tags.

Comment: There was also another problem where just editing the tags caused the code indentation in the post body to be changed. But it doesn't always happen, so I'll just leave this comment here in case someone else noticed it.

Comment: For reference: the difference is 3 trailing spaces vs. 1 space and 2 TABs, in line with "string path = String.Format(_pagesFormat, application, pageName);".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed, there are differences in the body:

https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/30cf2dfd-f193-476e-bc08-e94b424a54a3/view-source
https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/c59adca0-e591-45b3-b3b2-b77054425649/view-source

Save to disk and use a compare tool -- I don't want to ruin the mystery for you. :)

Comment: Ah... But to be clear, I didn't even give focus to the textarea. Maybe it's something wmd-editor does.