# Empty diff in edit history

Tags: support, bug, revisions-list

I was looking at the edit history for a question: https://money.stackexchange.com/posts/3388/revisions

Notice how edit #3 is supposed to be a tag edit, but the diff is blank:

[image: Question edit history]

Why?

Comment: Wild guess: the user did add a tag, but that tag has since been deleted (or synonymized into [investing]).

Comment: To add to @Glorfindel's comment, IIRC the tag is no longer shown in the revision history in these situations: a) Removed by the script which zaps single-occurrence tags. b) Merged by a mod into another tag. c) Burninated by a CM. I cannot tell for sure in this situation, but you can find some examples of tags removed by a script [in this chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22tagged/deleted-tag%22&room=10243). (Just in case you want to compare how the revision history is displayed there.)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Revision history suggests that I edited the post body, whereas I didn't](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40769/revision-history-suggests-that-i-edited-the-post-body-whereas-i-didnt) or [My edit didn't do anything, yet it is still shown](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/175431/339911)

Comment: @αλεχολυτ That does not answer my question. This situation is only about tags, and the diff does not appear at all. In contrast, that question is about edits to the body that did not seem to appear in the diff.

Comment: I agree with you on that @Flux, this isn't a propper duplicate, as that question only handles about post bodies. Martin's comment is a far more likely explanation.

Comment: Here is what SEDE shows in the PostHistory table for this specific post: https://data.stackexchange.com/money/query/1252003/posthistory-for-a-specific-post?id=3388 I am sure that people who know more about SQL can find some more efficient way to do this, but I have at least tried to find posts with tag edits which do not change the tags: https://data.stackexchange.com/money/query/1327770/tag-edits-which-do-not-change-tags So that we have more instances of this to examine. (Of course, they are more likely to tell you something on a site you're familiar with.)

Comment: Possibility: this could be caused by edits that were removed during the 5 minutes grace period.

Comment: @Flux My impression is that in such case the edit summary explicitly says "Edit removed during grace period". https://data.stackexchange.com/money/query/1067159/list-of-all-edits-where-edit-summary-contains-given-keyword?keyword=grace%20period

Comment: I unknowingly reproduced this here: [Doing a tag only edit on a previous revision doesn't do the expected roll-back](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/361831/doing-a-tag-only-edit-on-a-previous-revision-doesnt-do-the-expected-roll-back)